# Deploying app to Heroku with source-maps

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, source-maps, paas

Everything works perfect locally. I enabled source-maps in my webpack config and .map file is created. 
Problem is when I push app to Heroku. If I inspect element I see that source maps are not enabled. I minimize my code so nothing is where it's supposed to be without source-maps.
How do I deploy to Heroku with source-maps?

**EDIT:**

**webpack config**

```
devtool: 'source-map',
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules|dist|build/,
        options: {
          babelrc: true,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.local\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: ExtractLocal.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader?sourceMap',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                minimize: true,
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName: '[local]___[name]__[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
              options: {
                resources: [ path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client/styling/styles/variables.scss'), ],
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
     ],
  },
   plugins: [
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    }),
   ]
```

package.json

```
"build-client": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./src/build/bundle.js",
```

If I refresh my app on heroku and run heroku logs I get the below errors regarding source maps. H12 Request timeout. So Sourcemaps are there but are not being fetched by Heroku.

[image]

**SOLUTION**
Ok, I found the problem. It was **Nginx** and not Heroku. I am using it between my Heroku app and server. The configuration was set up like this.

```
location ~* \.(js|css|gif|png|jpg|ico|svg|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|json|xml)$ {
            root                 "/app/src/dist/";
            add_header         Pragma public;
            add_header         Cache-Control public;
      expires            1y;
      gzip_static        on;
      gzip               off;
      log_not_found      off;
      access_log         off;
 }
```

As you can see there is no **map** extension so it was not fetching it. After I added it, everything started working properly.

Comment: You need to post your webpack config so that we can see under what conditions you have sourcemap enabled. For example, if you have generation of sourcemap tied to process.env.NODE_ENV!== "production" then by default on Heroku you won't have a sourcemap, since NODE_ENV gets set to "production" on Heroku by default.

Comment: Hy Yoni. I posted my webpack config. I have differnt webpack config file for production and development so it is not that. Source maps are generated and I think that they even go to Heroku when I deploy because if I open the chrome devtool and start refreshing the page it is much slower then when I deploy without source maps. That means it is downloading source maps but when I inspect element I see no right line number or location.

Comment: Problem resolved. See Edit.